# Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

We have around 20 developers and want to implement continuous integration using Team foundation server 2010.

1. Currently we use VS2005 which we will upgrade to VS 2010 Premium Version
2. We will buy 1 Team Foundation Server license.

Then, can we use TFS 2010 to auto build and CI purpose? Or We should use CC.Net And nAnt?

Can anyone please look into this.

Regards,
Chandan

Comment: Can you edit your title ? It is vage.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can use TFS for this, it is one of its built in features. When you create a new build, one of the tabs in the "wizard" is dedicated to setting when you want the build to run, and you can set it to run everytime something is checked in (which is a CI build), or you can set it to save up its changes and run no more frequently than a specified period of time.

You don't need CC.Net or NAnt. TFS actually auto creates an MSBuild file which you can then extend if you want to do extra things with your build (like build MSIs, or deploy the built files to other locations, etc etc). If you have used NAnt then MSBuild will be kind of familiar, although there are a few diferences.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late:

You may run into some upgrade issues when converting code from VS2005 to VS2010. From VS2008 to VS2010 is fairly painless. Third party controls will make the upgrade irritating.

Also, you'll need at least one MSDN subscription for Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in order to get TFS 2010 server.  Unless of course the retail version of TFS 2010 is purchased separately. TFS 2010 server comes with 5 cal licenses. The others would need to be purchased separately at $500/ea, unless the rest of the development team is at least using VS2010 Pro.

Setting up basic build definitions, Manual, CI, gated, accrued are pretty straight forward and the way to go for building source.

What you'll also need to install TFS 2010 correctly:
Windows Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2008 R2 *SQL express implementation not supported by Microsoft. SSRS and SSAS features for TFS.
SharePoint Foundation 2010 (free and limited) or SharePoint Server 2010
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration works great on TFS 2010. You can very easily set it up to build, run your test, package and deploy. In TFS 2010 you use Windows Workflow to construct your build process. No more difficult to write and maintain MSBuild scripts if you don't want to.